# CVE-2020-9484: Which session persistence manager is vulnerable?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9

I was stumbling across CVE-2020-9484 (https://seclists.org/oss-sec/2020/q2/136).

Its vulnerability advisory states:

```
...
b) the server is configured to use the PersistenceManager with a
   FileStore; and
c) the PersistenceManager is configured with
   sessionAttributeValueClassNameFilter="null" (the default unless a
   SecurityManager is used) or a sufficiently lax filter to allow the
   attacker provided object to be deserialized; and
```

My question: Which session persistence manager is vulnerable (since often the PersistenceManager is referred to `org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManager`)?
`org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager` or `org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManager`, or both?

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/manager.html#Persistence_Across_Restarts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StandardManager` is not addressed by this security vulnerability: it stores all sessions in a single file of an applications temporary directory. If someone has write access to this file, he has probably access to the whole Tomcat installation.

With `PersistentManager` using `FileStore` the situation is different: every session is saved in a separate file, according to its `JSESSIONID`. Using a crafted `JSESSIONID` (probably by inserting `../../` in it, I didn't test) it is possible to point to any file in the filesystem (cf. [patch](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/commit/3aa8f28db7efb311cdd1b6fe15a9cd3b167a2222)).